# Delete previous message in Python aiogram FSM

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing a telegram bot using the aiogram library. I have a FSM module that shows the inline keyboard on every step except the last one. At each step, the keyboard message from the previous step is deleted, but the last message cannot be deleted. This is due to the fact that in the previous steps I use the callback_query_handler handlers, and in the last one I use message_handler.
Is there any way to remove the `await callback.message.answer('Введите максимальную цену:')` message after the user enters a number?

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from keyboards.client_keyboards import city_keyboard, district_keyboard, rooms_keyboard, floor_keyboard
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import datetime
from databases.users_db import sql_add_users_flat


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    city = State()
    district = State()
    # neighborhood = State()
    rooms = State()
    floor = State()
    # heating = State()
    price = State()


async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.city.set()
    await message.answer('Выбери город:', reply_markup=city_keyboard)
    # await message.delete()


async def canceling(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                    state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await callback.message.answer('ОК')
    await callback.answer()


async def city_choose(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                      state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
        data['name'] = callback.from_user.username
        data['city'] = callback.data
    await callback.message.delete()
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await callback.message.answer('Выбери район:', reply_markup=district_keyboard)


async def district_choose(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                          state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['district'] = callback.data
        data['neigborhood'] = None  # заполнитель для таблицы, пока не написана функция
    await callback.message.delete()
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await callback.message.answer('Выбери количество комнат:', reply_markup=rooms_keyboard)


async def rooms_choose(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                       state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['rooms'] = callback.data
    await callback.message.delete()
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await callback.message.answer('Выбери этаж:', reply_markup=floor_keyboard)


async def floor_choose(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                       state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['floor'] = callback.data
        data['heating'] = None  # заполнитель для таблицы, пока не написана функция
    await callback.message.delete()
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await callback.message.answer('Введите максимальную цену:')


# async def heating_choose(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
#                           state: FSMContext):
#     async with state.proxy() as data:
#         data['heating'] = callback.data
#     await callback.message.delete()
#     await FSMAdmin.next()
#     await callback.message.answer('Введи макcимальную цену:')

async def max_price_choose(message: types.Message,
                           state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        try:
            data['price'] = int(message.text)
        except Exception:
            await message.reply('Введи число нормально')
    await message.answer(
        f"Выбранные параметры:\nГород: {data['city']}\nРайон: {data['district']}"
        f"\nКоличество комнат: {data['rooms']}\nЭтаж: {data['floor']}\nМаксимальная цена: {data['price']}")
    await message.delete()
    try:
        await sql_add_users_flat(state)
        await message.answer('Выбор сохранен')
    except Exception:
        await message.answer('Произошла ошибка, изменения не сохранены')
    await state.finish()


def register_handlers_survey(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, text='Выбрать параметры', state=None)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(canceling, text='Отменить', state='*')
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(city_choose, state=FSMAdmin.city)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(district_choose, state=FSMAdmin.district)
    # dp.register_callback_query_handler(neighbohood_choose, state=FSMAdmin.neighbourhood)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(rooms_choose, state=FSMAdmin.rooms)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(floor_choose, state=FSMAdmin.floor)
    # dp.register_callback_query_handler(heating_choose, state=FSMAdmin.rooms)
    dp.register_message_handler(max_price_choose, state=FSMAdmin.price)
```

This is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handle_price` -> to process the user's input and delete the previous message. Called from the process_price message handler, triggered when the user enters a message in the FSMAdmin.price state.

Try running this code:

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from keyboards.client_keyboards import city_keyboard, district_keyboard, rooms_keyboard, floor_keyboard
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import datetime
from databases.users_db import sql_add_users_flat

class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    city = State()
    district = State()
    # neighborhood = State()
    rooms = State()
    floor = State()
    # heating = State()
    price = State()

async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.city.set()
    await message.answer('Выбери город:', reply_markup=city_keyboard)
    # await message.delete()


async def canceling(callback: types.CallbackQuery,
                    state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await callback.message.answer('ОК')
    await callback.answer()


async def handle_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Process the user's input here...

    # Delete the previous message!
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)

    # Transition to the next state
    await FSMAdmin.next_state()
    await message.answer('Введите максимальную цену:')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.price)
async def process_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await handle_price(message, state)
```